# Is a newspaper/magazine editor considered an author or an editor in terms of referencing?

Tags: citations

Should I reference him/her as a normal author or as an editor using the abbreviation 'ed.' (Harvard style)?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, magazine and news articles include the author name at the beginning or the end of the article, or at least some short form like an abbreviation that denotes the relevant author that you could look up. This is the person you ought to refer to as 'author'.

If you're not sure about the author, it would be better denote the editor as the 'editor' not as an author. It would be best to contact the editor to know the identity of the author if possible. But this would not always apply since a few authors prefer anonymity in certain articles.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that my question falls in case where there's no clear author, just a name and the word 'editor' beside it.

Comment: @R.AS.: Then the second paragraph would apply. Anyway, the first paragraph would serve to add clarity.

Comment: But I am confused, aren't all newspapers/magazines authors actually 'editors'?

Comment: @R.AS.: It is ambiguous when you look at this as there is a clear meaning when you use the term *journal editors* but not the same in this case. At times it is similar to a *journal editor*; an editor's job would be to compile the articles they collect from the concerned authors.

Comment: Exactly. That's my point. Unlike a journal or a book editor, newspapers/magazines editors are the majority I think...

Comment: @R.AS.: Well, it would be better to confirm whether the concerned editor is *really* the author of the article. Otherwise it would be perfectly safe to refer to them as just the editor of the article.

Comment: "Usually, magazine and news articles include the author name at the beginning or the end of the article." - this may be culture-specific. At least in Germany, newspaper articles often only feature an author code consisting of two or three letters. Often, you can find a mapping to real names somewhere, but I am not sure its existence is guaranteed. This custom seems to declining in online newspapers, but it's common in printed versions.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I agree; just made the edit on the abbreviation/code.